# Perform Google Firebase Query with multiple inputs in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android app using google firebase. In this i have the query working with one input using .equalsTo as shown below:

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = mCarDatabase.orderByChild("make").equalTo(make);
```

As show it orders by car make and takes in a string with the make. I have am not sure how to approach adding another string input to the query for example i wanted to search the query by model too and what i tried was adding another .equalTo(model) but that breaks the application. Any assistance here would be a great help thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use one `orderByChild()` or one `orderByKey()` but there are different queries that you can use like:

```
limitToFirst()
limitToLast()
startAt()
endAt()
equalTo()
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html

Comment: is there any way to perform a query with multiple strings ?

Comment: @DanielM96 what you are thinking about does not work as said in the first answer here and in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase (but there are some workarounds there)